# fs.readdir failing on and don't know why

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs

Running a node app to read a directory

```
fs.readdirSync('‎/Users/edwardthompson/Dropbox/Apps/EvidentiaSoftware/records/thompson-hayward');
```

I consistently get

```
 Stack:
    error properties: Object({ errno: -2, syscall: 'scandir', code: 'ENOENT', path: '‎/Users/edwardthompson/Dropbox/Apps/EvidentiaSoftware/records/thompson-hayward' })
    Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir '‎/Users/edwardthompson/Dropbox/Apps/EvidentiaSoftware/records/thompson-hayward'
```

But I know the directory is there

```
ls -al /Users/edwardthompson/Dropbox/Apps/EvidentiaSoftware/records/thompson-hayward
    total 0
    drwxr-xr-x@ 9 edwardthompson  staff  288 Jan 18  2019 .
    drwxr-xr-x@ 6 edwardthompson  staff  192 Aug 29 12:30 ..
    drwxr-xr-x@ 9 edwardthompson  staff  288 Jan 18  2019 Births
    drwxr-xr-x@ 4 edwardthompson  staff  128 Jan 18  2019 Census
    drwxr-xr-x@ 3 edwardthompson  staff   96 Jan 18  2019 Deaths
    drwxr-xr-x@ 7 edwardthompson  staff  224 Jan 18  2019 Marriages
    drwxr-xr-x@ 4 edwardthompson  staff  128 Jan 18  2019 Military
    drwxr-xr-x@ 3 edwardthompson  staff   96 Jan 18  2019 Other
    drwxr-xr-x@ 8 edwardthompson  staff  256 Jan 18  2019 books
```

Not sure how to proceed

fs.lstat gives me the same ENOENT results.  The Dropbox directory has extended attributes (can't find getfattr)

I tried /user/... and it did not make a difference

Comment: maybe a permissions issue with access to the `/Users/edwardthompson/` directory. is your node environment running with the same user, or one with the proper group to have access?

Comment: Maybe try adding the harddrive letter to the path like `C:/...`

Comment: FYI the path in the stack output starts with `/User/` and in your function call and `ls` call it starts with `/Users`/

Comment: /User/ was a copy paste error on my part (I was trying something).  C:/ has no meaning on a linux or macos file system. I keep trying to see if its permissions somehow, but I am running as myself and I can do it

Comment: Does node fs.readdir have issues with extended attributes (xattr)?

Comment: If you intend for the path to start with be `/Users/`, then please edit your question to show the correct code and errors.  Otherwise, we're chasing ghosts.

Comment: @ed4becky Have you tried having the node application read from a different location? You could also try `getfattr` on the directory and see what the output is.

Comment: I've seen this error when the path was symlinked (or maybe a subpath of the path is a symlink?). This also happens on older MacOS because the home folder was lowercase (while displayed as `/Users/`). did you try `lstat`?

Comment: see results of your recommendations in edited version.  Basically, no change...  This particular directory does not have a symlink

Comment: I think it might have something to do with the extended attributes of that directory. Can you add the result of `xattr`.

Comment: Found the issue but I don't understand it.      let p = '\/Users/edwardthompson/Dropbox/Apps/EvidentiaSoftware/records/thompson-hayward'; removes a hidden? character that is inserted before the path, but if I just do     let p = '/Users/edwardthompson/Dropbox/Apps/EvidentiaSoftware/records/thompson-hayward';  a hidden character gets inserted as the first character, corrupting the path.  Why would I have to escape the first forward slash?

Comment: @ed4becky did you copy paste the path from somewhere or type it manually? Does re-typing the path manually help with that hidden char?

Comment: @exside I tried both

Comment: Are any of the directories in the path symlinks if so node needs to be told to follow symlinks?

Comment: Does this also happen when Dropbox is not running?

Answer (score 5):

```
const path = require('path');

const dirName = path.join(__dirname, '‎/ (../)x? /records/thompson-hayward');
```

> (../)x? replace this with ../ how many times you need

```
fs.readdirSync(dirName).forEach(folder => {
// code here
});
```

Comment: path.join gave me : /Users/edwardthompson/IdeaProjects/evidentia4/src/app/services/‎<something here>/Users/edwardthompson/Dropbox/Apps/EvidentiaSoftware/records/thompson-hayward, which of course is wrong, BUT it revealed some hidden character between the two paths.  I noticed that the error message I usually get has a space befor ethe base of the path - this one did not.

Comment: ths ../ approach won't work for my app - the directory is hardcoded now but will be based on user selection.

Answer (score 2):

You could try using `path.resolve()`:

`fs.readdirSync(path.resolve(‘Users’, ‘edwardthompson’, ‘Dropbox’, ‘Apps’, ‘EvidentiaSoftware’, ‘records’, ‘thompson-hayward’));`

Comment: oddly, the path resolve gave me /Users/edwardthompson/IdeaProjects/evidentia4/Users/edwardthompson/Dropbox/Apps/EvidentiaSoftware/records/thompson-hayward

Answer (score 2):

"/Users/edwardthompson/Dropbox/Apps/EvidentiaSoftware/records/thompson-hayward" is not the correct path – this path starts with / which is the root directory.

With Linux the ./ is a shortcut to the current directory.

Try Something like this "./Users/edwardthompson/Dropbox/Apps/EvidentiaSoftware/records/thompson-hayward"

here is a link to a working example showing a similar error if you omit the .
https://repl.it/@joshuaaguilar20/FrequentFunctionalFraction

```
      var fs = require('fs');

fs.writeFile('./newFile.txt', 'Hello World', function(error){
  if(error){
    throw error;
  } else {
    console.log('success');
  }
});

/* let wrong = fs.readdirSync("/newDir", function (err) {
  console.log(err)
}) */

/* 
Returns Error 
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir '/newDir'
    at Object.readdirSync (fs.js:790:3)
    at evalmachine.<anonymous>:11:12
    at Script.runInContext (vm.js:133:20)
    at Object.runInContext (vm.js:311:6)
    at evaluate (/run_dir/repl.js:133:14)
    at ReadStream.<anonymous> (/run_dir/repl.js:116:5)
    at ReadStream.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:288:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:269:11)
    at ReadStream.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:224:10)

 */


//Correct 

let x = fs.readdirSync("./newDir", function (err) {
  //adding ./ allows unix to find the Dir 
  console.log(err)
})

console.log(x)
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to debug would be to try reading a different dir located in /Users/{username}. If it works, you might want to look into symlink issues with readdir. It is likely that Dropbox creates a symlink that is not properly resolved.

You can use [`fs.realpath()` or `fs.realpathSync`](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/fs.html#fs_fs_realpathsync_path_options) to obtain the realpath of the dir you're looking for, and then use readdir on the realpath instead.

Comment: this worked for me thank you so much! readdirSync worked locally on my Mac, but in a docker container that uses Ubuntu it failed. So i had to use realpathSync('/some/path') like you suggested and pass the result of that into fs.readdirSync

Answer (score 0):

You can do some diagnostic work on the path with the hidden character and perhaps learn something about what it is.

If this creates the problem path:

```
let p = '/Users/edwardthompson/Dropbox/Apps/EvidentiaSoftware/records/thompson-hayward';
```

Then, you can do this to see what that first character is:

```
 console.log(p.charCodeAt(0));
```

Or, output all the char codes in the string:

```
console.log(p.split("").map(chr => chr.charCodeAt(0).toString()).join(","));
```

Here it is in a runnable snippet (which does not reproduce your problem on my computer, but might show something on yours):

```js
let p = '/Users/edwardthompson/Dropbox/Apps/EvidentiaSoftware/records/thompson-hayward';
let charCodes = p.split("").map(chr => chr.charCodeAt(0));
let str = charCodes.map((code, index) => {
    return `<tr><td>${p.charAt(index)}</td><td>${code.toString()}</td><td> 0x${code.toString(16)}</td></tr>`
}).join("");
document.write(`<style>table.colright td:nth-child(2), table.colright th:nth-child(2), table.colright td:nth-child(3), table.colright th:nth-child(3) {
  text-align: right;
}</style>`);
document.write("<table class='colright'>")
document.write("<thead><tr><th>&nbsp;char<br>&nbsp;</th><th>&nbsp;decimal<br>value</th><th>hex<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;value</th></tr></thead>");    
document.write("<tbody>");
document.write(str);
document.write("</tbody></table>");
```

My only working theory (which is an unsubstantiated guess) is that somehow the `/U` that starts the string is being interpreted as the beginning of a manually specified unicode character on your system only.  It's supposed to be `\u` as the unicode prefix, not `/U`, but it's certainly acting like somehow it is misinterpreting the `/U`.

---

FYI, you might also want to do this:

```
console.log(path.sep)
```

just to make sure your path separator isn't somehow haywire for your platform.